# Type "Time" in SQL Server and C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, types

Is there any way that I can create the type time in C# to be compatible with the type time of the SQL server?

Answer (score 21):

According to MSDN:

[Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx?PHPSESSID=lm71lj7i6gj5fjtebtb2srl4n3)

You're looking for the **TimeSpan** type.

Answer (score 1):

try using the below date formatter in C#.

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
string text = dateTime.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss.fff");

This will lead to the same format as sql date format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff'

Thanks!